# What are these two smd components?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I fried these two components by plugging in the battery the wrong way. What are they? I read SMDs have an ID which helps identify them but since they are burned i cannot read the ID. If i replace them would it be possible to use a similar component?

[image]

Comment: what is `similar component`?

Comment: Both the parts are labelled Q-XX. Q is a letter commonly used for transistors. Similar to how R is for resistors

Comment: If two transistors are broken with visible damage, there are probably more broken things on the board. How much is it worth to you to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

They are transistors. Withou seeing what reads on them your only hope is to find an identical working board to look at the components to find replacements. Unless you can find schematics or service manual for whatever this is.

Answer (score 1):

Transistors or MOSFETs. Since there’s so many kinds of both you will either need to get the schematic or reverse-engineer the board and make your own schematic. Given that the board basically fried itself I suspect it is a design that is in need of improvement...